# Seaman Schengen Transit visa is valid to go tour in Spain

Tags: schengen, transit, transit-visas

Good day
Here I have one question with you guys. I am a seaman I mean working on a ship. So I have valid multiple c grade Transit Schengen visa from Spain that visa is one year validity . So now I am on work break  .my next joining in the ship two month to go. So I would like to go for tour in Spain Madrid, is this visa eligible for me to go Spain for tour?  There any problems....pls kindly answer me about this.[image]

Answer (score -4):

You need to apply for Schengen tourist visa. It’s impossible for you to travel to Spain with airport transit visa

Comment: The visa in question is not an airport transit visa, however.  It is a short-stay (type C) visa with the word "transit" written on it.